# How to make inline comments in snort rule file?

Tags: snort

One of my assignments requires me to provide inline comments for the snort rule.

It should look something like:

```
alert \ (some comment initiator here) comment

any \ (explanation)
any \ (explanation)
```

and so on...

How would I make inline comments with Snort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [Snort manual](http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com).  Comments are created in the configuration and rules files with the pound sign, which is pretty typical of UNIX type things:

```
 alert tcp any any -> any 0 (sid:1000000;msg:"Packet to port zero.";) # Example rule with comment
```